# RIA Services JSON and Ext.Js

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, service, ria

We using Sencha Ext JS 4 for our LOB Application. On the server we use MS RIA services ( Data Domain Services ) with JSON endpoint. In general everything working ok.But paging is not. 
first of all we discovered that JSON request URL had keywords that RIA simply ignored ( state, page etc. ) after some research I found out that I can use following syntax :

For Example:

```
http://localhost/Product/ServiceName.svc/JSON/GetItems?_dc=1328305056811&$take=50&$skip=50
```

i.e. $skip ( if you use $skip - you have to sort query on RIA side ) and $take, request like that return appropriate number of records. However 
JSON response looks like this at the beginning:

```
{"GetItemsResult":{"TotalCount":-1,"RootResults":[
```

i.e. TotalCount = -1 - in order for paging to work properly JS needs to know total number of records and the only way I can see this working - if I query number of records with separate request and then do page query.

Question is do I miss something ? It is possible for RIA Service to return correct TotalCount ( if there is not $skip or $take - RIA Service send back entire table and specify TotalCount correctly ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I don't know much about the technology you are using on the server side. I am using Grails and cannot be happier. So I cant help you much with your total count.

However for the paging paramters ExtJS allows for translation of what it expects to send/receive to what your server side expects. Like this:

```
proxy:{
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'request/my.json',
    //override default param names
    startParam : "offset",
    limitParam :"max",
    sortParam : "sort",
    simpleSortMode:true,//required for directionParam to be used
    directionParam : "order",
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    },
```

On another thought: if you cant make your server side send total count, create a listener on the store and count the records manually on load and set it into the totalCOunt property of the store.

Good luck.
Dmitry.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the inlinecount option:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942040(v=prot.10).aspx

Comment: Not working $inlinecount=allpages generate :Invalid query operator 'inlinecount'.
 Parameter name: queryOperator